# Load a driver as a module at boot time

Tags: drivers, kernel, intel

I have an Intel 10 Gigabit XF SR/AF Dual Fiber Port PCI-Express Network Adapter in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server that I am unable to get working.

According to [this man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/ixgbe.4freebsd.html), it's compatible with Ubuntu but requires loading the module. I have never loaded a module before.

The command "ifconfig` doesn't list the nic in the output.

The command `lshw` lists the nic as disabled and `(network:0 UNCLAIMED)`

The command `lspci` shows the following information:

```
Ethernet Controller: Intel Corp 82598 10GBE PCI-Express Ethernet Controller (rev 01)
```

The command `sudo modprobe -v ixbge` produces this output

```
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/drivers/net/mdio.ko t 
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/udp_tunnel.ko  
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/net/ipv6/ip6_udp_tunnel‌​.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/drivers/net/vxlan.ko
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/in‌tel/ixgbe/ixgbe.ko
```

UPDATE: I apologize for the delay. Please click the link below to see the output from the command  *lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0200]'*.

the highlighted portion of the pic shows the 10GB nic listed.

[Please click here for the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZLoR.jpg)
Here's the output -

Comment: Can you please test `sudo modprobe -v ixgbe` and let us know the result?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I will post the results later tonight. Thank you

Comment: insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/drivers/net/mdio.ko _____                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/udp_tunnel.ko _____
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/net/ipv6/ip6_udp_tunnel.ko ____
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/drivers/net/vxlan.ko_________
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe.ko

Comment: Thanks! And, sorry, I should have said please [edit] your question to add information like that output :) You've loaded the module now (it was available and loadable and not already loaded). Does the device work? If so, you can configure something, probably systemd, to load the driver at boot time. I'm going to sleep now, but others may well notice your question and answer it before I come back, especially if you edit it to add updates.

Comment: That's good news! I will test the adapter later this evening and post my results. So sorry for the format of my previous comment. Pasting into the comment field is not working to well for me. thank you!

Comment: Now I can see the 10GB nic listed in the output after running the command "lshw", but it's listed as (network:0 UNCLAIMED).  I cannot see the nic listed when i run "ifconfig".  the "lshw" output is shown below. Also, the nic is listed as disabled in Dell open manage. any ideas?

Comment: *-network:0 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82598 10GbE PCI-Express Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df2c0000-df2dffff ioport:ecc0(size=32) memory:df2b8000-df2bbfff

Comment: Ok, so loading that driver is not enough, and I don't know the answer to your question. Sorry for not getting to the real problem sooner. The people who might know will need to know the chipset of the device which I'm guessing plugs into a USB port, in which case the necessary info should show up in the output of `lsusb`. Could you [edit] your question and add the output there?

Comment: @Zanna It's a PCI-E NIC. ixgbe should support it. What does `ip link`show? `ifconfig` only lists cards that are up by default.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0200]'`? That should reveal the PCI device ID of the network adapter. Thanks.

Comment: @vidario and David sorry for the delay. I will try your suggestions and post the output this evening.